# CakePHP 3.0 Save data in to tables

Tags: cakephp, notifications

I'm trying to create a log system for users `add` and notificate the admins when a new user has been added, asking him permissions to let the new user login.

Anyone knows if there is a plugin for it available? Or how can I save this data in two tables.

I've tried this

```
public function add() {
  $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
  $log = $this->Logs->newEntity();
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
    $user->criado_por = $this->Auth->user('nome');
    $user->modificado_por = $this->Auth->user('nome');
    $user->userstatus = 'waiting for permitions';

    $log->date = date::now();
    $log->newuser = $user->name;
    $log->whocreate = $this->Auth->User('name');

    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
      $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
      return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    } else {
      $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
  }
  $this->set(compact('user'));
  $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a notification plugin for CakePHP: [Notifier](https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-notifier)